# google cloud print not working with phonegap

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-print

I'm working on a simple phonegap app that prints a simple pdf page to test Google cloud printing, I followed steps mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/gadget).
It's working fine in a browser but when I tried it on a mobile, nothing was printed, I  wasn't even able to save it to my Google drive.
Here is my code:

```
var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page",
       "http://www.google.com/landing/cloudprint/testpage.pdf");
gadget.openPrintDialog();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue too, it can be solved using a simple http request.
at first you have to add [InAppBrowser](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser), then you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/mohamed-salah/PrintPlugin_GoogleCloud) for printing, it supports Google Cloud Print on Android and AirPrint on iOS

after adding printing plugin, it can be used as below:

```
var type = "text/html"
var title = "test.html";
var fileContent = "<html>Phonegap Print Plugin</html>";
window.PrintPlugin.print(fileContent,function(){console.log('success')},function(){console.log('fail')},"",type,title);
```

Comment: Device plugin (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device) is also needed for your plugin to work. Thanks for your plugin

Comment: Dear Hazem Hagrass I am very new to this phonegap. Please guide me the process. I am searching for this for a long time.

Comment: @Saikat: just open the plugin page on github and you will find the steps

Comment: @Hazem Hagress: I downlod the zip file and make a app of that. Open that app in tablet. Can see the Print button also. But nothing happens when i press the Print button. I am so confused. How to exactly make the printer work. I have already connect a printer to could. But can't open it through an app.

Comment: @Saikat just add device plugin first via phonegap cli: "cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git"

Comment: @Hazem Hagress: As you know I am very new to this phone gap. So please tell me the process in details. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Hazem Hagress: Will you please make a little prototype of it and help me to understand the process.

Comment: Dear @HazemHagrass, the asker has posted an example of printing a pdf file. <br/>The plugin you proposed allows printing pdf or text/html documents only?

Comment: I have a same problem but i did not use phonegap, I am using free service from web to convert my web app into android app. Before converting everything working good but after converting to apk file. google cloud print not working. if there is any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

at first it didn't work with me then I added [Device](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_device_device.md.html#Device) plugin to make it work.